# invalid version: +incompatible suffix not allowed: module contains a go.mod file, so semantic import versioning is required

Tags: go

When I run go build, there is always an error:

> go: finding github.com/shirou/gopsutil v2.19.6+incompatible
>
> go list -m: github.com/shirou/gopsutil@v2.19.6+incompatible: invalid version: +incompatible suffix not allowed: module contains a go.mod file, so semantic import versioning is required

How can I fix it?

I use go mod  and
go version 1.13.5

Answer (score 1):

After go 1.13, new validation has been added.

This is new validation in 1.13
see `Version validation` in https://golang.org/doc/go1.13 for details.

To fix this, go down to version 1.13,

or

Changed `go.mod` to add `v2` in module `module github.com/shirou/gopsutil` -> `module github.com/shirou/gopsutil/v2`

here is [link](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil/issues/663#issuecomment-533882381) detail